# How can I stop this from writing a value to all dictionaries? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

**Intro**
So I have stumbled across this problem yesterday, and I've been stumped trying to figure this out myself. I only have this problem with JavaScript.

**Problem**
I've been creating a programming language with JS since the start of this week, and I was enjoying myself the entire week making it. The problem here is that when I carry dictionaries across functions, it has some problems reading and writing into those dictionaries. When I check the console logs, I see that not just the dictionary in the function was written, but all of the instances of that dictionary were written.

**Code**
Here is the code to *graph.js*:

```js
function codeToArray(code) {
    let codeArray = {commands:[], vars:{x:{value:0, read_only:true},y:{value:0, read_only:false}}};
    
    let commands = code.split("\n");
    
    for (i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
        let command = commands[i];
        let inputs = command.split(" ");
        
        if (inputs[0].toLowerCase() !== ";") {
            
            // Arithmetics
            if (inputs[0].toLowerCase() === "+") { // Addition
                codeArray.commands.push({name:"add", variable:inputs[1], value:inputs[2], syntax_id:1});
            } else if (inputs[0].toLowerCase() === "-") { // Subtraction
                codeArray.commands.push({name:"subtract", variable:inputs[1], value:inputs[2], syntax_id:1});
            } else if (inputs[0].toLowerCase() === "*") { // Multiplication
                codeArray.commands.push({name:"multiply", variable:inputs[1], value:inputs[2], syntax_id:1});
            } else if (inputs[0].toLowerCase() === "/") { // Division
                codeArray.commands.push({name:"divide", variable:inputs[1], value:inputs[2], syntax_id:1});
            }
            
            // I/O
            else if (inputs[0].toLowerCase() === ":") { // Set
                codeArray.commands.push({name:"set", variable:inputs[1], value:inputs[2], syntax_id:1});
            }
            
            // Conditional Statements
            else if (inputs[0].toLowerCase() === "if") { // If Statement
                let ifCommand = "";
                
                for (j = 4; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                    if (j > 4) {
                        ifCommand += " " + inputs[j];
                    } else {
                        ifCommand += inputs[j];
                    }
                }
                
                let ifCommandArray = codeToArray(ifCommand).commands[0];
                
                codeArray.commands.push({name:"if", value1:inputs[1], condition:inputs[2], value2:inputs[3], command:ifCommandArray, syntax_id:2});
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    return codeArray
}

function parseValue(value, variables) {
    let return_value = value;

    console.log(value);
    console.log(variables);

    if (value.charAt(0) === "$") {
    let variable_name = return_value.substring(1, value.length);
    console.log(variable_name);

    let variable = variables[variable_name];
    console.log(variable);

    if (variable === undefined) {
            return_value = NaN;
    } else {
        return_value = variable.value;
    }
    } else {
    return_value = parseFloat(value);
    }

    console.log(return_value);

    return return_value
}

function runCodeArray(commands, variables) {
    for (i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
        let command = commands[i];
        
        if (command.syntax_id === 1) { // Simple Syntax (Variable Value Syntax)
            if (command.name === "add") { // Addition
                let variable = variables[command.variable];
                
                if (variable === undefined) {
                    let error_message = `Variable cannot be found (line ${i+1} ignoring comments)`;
                    
                    return {commands:commands, variables:variables, return_message:error_message};
                }
                
                if (variable.read_only === true) {
                    let error_message = `A read-only variable was trying to be written (line ${i+1} ignoring comments)`;
                    
                    return {commands:commands, variables:variables, return_message:error_message};
                }
                
                let value = parseValue(command.value, variables);
                
                if (value === NaN) {
                    let error_message = `The value parameter is invalid (line ${i+1} ignoring comments)`;
                    
                    return {commands:commands, variables:variables, return_message:error_message};
                }
                
                variable.value += value;
            } else if (command.name === "set") { // Set
                let variable = variables[command.variable];
                
                if (variable === undefined) {
                    variables[command.variable] = {value:0, read_only:false};
            variable = variables[command.variable];
                }
                
                if (variable.read_only === true) {
                    let error_message = `A read-only variable was trying to be written (line ${i+1} ignoring comments)`;
                    
                    return {commands:commands, variables:variables, return_message:error_message};
                }
                
                let value = parseValue(command.value, variables);
                
                if (value === NaN) {
                    let error_message = `The value parameter is invalid (line ${i+1} ignoring comments)`;
                    
                    return {commands:commands, variables:variables, return_message:error_message};
                }
                
                variable.value = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return {commands:commands, variables:variables, return_message:true};
}

var url_string = ...graph.html?pattern=%3A+a+42%0D%0A%3A+b+%24a%0D%0A%3A+c+%24b%0D%0A // window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var pattern = url.searchParams.get("pattern");

let codeArray = codeToArray(pattern);

// console.log(codeArray);

let codeArrayOut = runCodeArray(codeArray.commands, codeArray.vars); // Will return true in return_message if everything is good, and will return a string in return_message if an error occurs.

// console.log(codeArrayOut);

if (codeArrayOut.return_message !== true) {
    alert("Error: " + codeArrayOut.return_message);
}
```

Sorry if the code is too long, boring or messy for you to read. Here is the function that's causing the most problems:

```js
function parseValue(value, variables) {
    let return_value = value;

    console.log(value);
    console.log(variables);

    if (value.charAt(0) === "$") {
    let variable_name = return_value.substring(1, value.length);
    console.log(variable_name);

    let variable = variables[variable_name];
    console.log(variable);

    if (variable === undefined) {
            return_value = NaN;
    } else {
        return_value = variable.value;
    }
    } else {
    return_value = parseFloat(value);
    }

    console.log(return_value);

    return return_value
}
```

**Outro**
I'm still learning in JavaScript, so I hope that you can solve this problem (because I can't).

Comment: "*all of the instances of that dictionary*" - that sounds like you didn't have multiple "instances" at all, but just one, and were writing to one and the same dictionary every time.

Comment: Can you please make a [mcve] including the code you pass to `codeToArray` (instead of some url parameter)? Which dictionary specifically are you talking about? Where do you instantiate it, where do you attempt to copy/clone it to create multiple instances?